# How input_dim parameter used in case of many hidden layers in a Multi Layer Perceptron in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

How the input_dim parameter used in different cases with Dense function in case of Multi Layer Perceptron (MLP) in Keras?

I have tried and seen the below observation in case of Sequential Model:

1. The input_dim parameter is always passed as part of Dense() function when adding very first hidden layer in the MLP
2. The input_dim parameter is never passed as part of Dense() function for other hidden layers (e.g. 2nd layer, 3rd layer, 4th layer, etc) or output layer in the MLP

```py
# To create a Sequential model
model_batch_drop_5lyr = Sequential()

# Hidden Layer1
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dense(684, activation='relu', input_dim = input_dim, kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.025, seed=None)))
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(BatchNormalization())
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dropout(0.5)) # 50% no. of neurons droped

# Hidden Layer2
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.050, seed=None)))
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(BatchNormalization())
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dropout(0.5)) # 50% no. of neurons droped

# Hidden Layer3
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dense(356, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.075, seed=None)))
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(BatchNormalization())
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dropout(0.5)) # 50% no. of neurons droped

# Hidden Layer4
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dense(228, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.125, seed=None)))
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(BatchNormalization())
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dropout(0.5)) # 50% no. of neurons droped

# Hidden Layer5
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.155, seed=None)))
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(BatchNormalization())
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dropout(0.5)) # 50% no. of neurons droped

# Output Layer
model_batch_drop_5lyr.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='softmax'))

# Printing Summary of the model with 3 hidden layers
print(model_batch_drop_5lyr.summary())
```

Why do we use input dimension only in hidden layer1. What are other scenario where input_dim can be used for other layers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input_dim` is very similar to the `input_shape` parameter, which is also only typically used in the first layer. Both tells keras what is the dimensionality of the input data to the first layer, from where shape inference can be performed for that and subsequent layers.

`input_dim = n` is equivalent to `input_shape = (n,)`, and you use in the layer that receives the input because the input is the only unknown to keras, the user needs to specify the expected shape of the input.